# Remote Automation Issue in Safari

Tags: selenium-webdriver, safari

I am trying to open a new tab in safari with Command+click combination on my Mac using Selenium.

```
String a = Keys.chord(Keys.COMMAND, Keys.ENTER);

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[text()='En savoir plus']")).sendKeys(a);
```

I have enabled to remote automation option in safari. When I am running the above code, I am getting a pop, asking me to disable the remote automation option.

Any pointers will be appreciated.

Thanks